# MySql grant permissions only to read something not whole table

Tags: mysql

I want to protect my database better, because, if someone decompiles my program, he will have my sql uid and password and can use them to steal my data. How can I grant permissions to the sql user, that I use for my program, to SELECT and UPDATE only when there is a WHERE or a LIKE in the sql statement? Because if someone finds out the user, he can steal my whole table. Thanks.

This is allowed : 
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = 'username'

This is not allowed:
    SELECT * FROM table

Comment: Have you thought of using views?

Comment: @P.Salmon nope, i didn't hear about that. Views can help me with what i want to do?

Comment: Maybe you should do a bit of research here's a starter http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-sql-views.aspx

Comment: @P.Salmon i read about the views, for what i understood that dose not  stop the intruder to select my hole view and steal all the passwords.

Comment: It sounds like you have a much larger problem than you imagine.  If database credentials are embedded in your program, then you have effectively no security at all.  The program does not need to be decompiled -- a hex editor will likely suffice.  You cannot embed anything in a program that you would not be willing to permit the user of the program to have, directly.

Comment: so all the examples I have seen on internet have the mysql username and password in the connection string. If I obfuscate my program will fix the hex editor vulnerability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the advantages of using a [Database View](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-sql-views.aspx) is that `A database view helps limit data access to specific users. You may not want a subset of sensitive data can be queryable by all users. You can use a database view to expose only non-sensitive data to a specific group of users.`

So, in theory, you might try something like

```
CREATE VIEW user_username AS SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = 'username'
```

in order to create separate views for every user of your application.

That being said, it is a very bad idea to do so. Also, **if by decompiling, a user has access to a database containing ALL the users**, the I am pretty sure there must be **something wrong** with the design of the application.

But, as very few details are given about the application in question, it is hard to advise as to how it should be done.

Comment: in my program i have a connection string to my database with uid and password, so here i am wrong? i have to do something else to connect to my db.

Comment: What if the program used a [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) associated to each user in order to connect to an end-point? A uuid is almost impossible to guess, and if someone is using random uuid's in order to do bad stuff, it's pretty obvious that berson deserves a good old **permanent ban**.

Comment: so your are suggesting separate uid's for each user that  connects to database.  I think even with this if my program is decompiled the db will be stealed. Because the hacker will find my function that  generate the uid.

Comment: You see, you make a request to the server. The server then saves in the database located there a new user and it's associated uuid, then sends back the uuid to the application. Fron here on out, every request to that server must be accompanied by that unique uuid associated to a unique user.

Comment: All the app needs to know in order to make requests to the server is just an URL + uuid and nothing more. All the server needs to know in order to identify the user that has made a request is also just the uuid.